# Error importing python 3rd party lib to Jython

Tags: import, module, jython, smartcard

I tried to import smartcard (from pyscard) to Jython, but it fails. I added the path as suggested:

```
>>> sys.path.append("C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages")
>>> sys.path.append("C:\Python26\Dll")
>>> sys.path.append("C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk")
>>> sys.path.append("C:\Python26\lib\plat-win")
>>> print sys.path
['', 'C:\\jython2.5.2\\Lib', '__classpath__', '__pyclasspath__/',     'C:\\jython2.5.2\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python26\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python26\\Lib', 'C:\\Python26\\Dll', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python26\\lib\\plat-win']
>>> import smartcard
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\smartcard\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
  from smartcard.System import listReaders
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\smartcard\System.py", line 27, in <module>
  import smartcard.reader.ReaderFactory
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\smartcard\reader\ReaderFactory.py", line 34, in   <module>
  from smartcard.pcsc.PCSCReader import PCSCReader
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\smartcard\pcsc\PCSCReader.py", line 27, in <module>
  from smartcard.pcsc.PCSCContext import PCSCContext
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\smartcard\pcsc\PCSCContext.py", line 27, in <module>
  from smartcard.scard import *
File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\smartcard\scard\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  from smartcard.scard._scard import *
ImportError: No module named _scard
```

However in my python it works fine. Any one has advice on this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to import a native C wrapper library into the Java VM? I'm not amazed if that would fail.

Answer (score 1):

You could use javax.smartcardio in Jython to access smart cards. Importing pyscard is not possible.